# Aplicación se cierra al actualizar ads

Tags: android-studio, admob

La aplicación funciona correctamente con este código:

```
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Cuando actualizo:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
```

Por:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.3'
```

La aplicacion se cierra al abrirla

Comment: y que error da el log cat?

Comment: Es importante agregar el mensaje del LogCat para que esta pregunta sea de ayuda a otros miembros de la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

```
******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#update_your_androidmanifestxml to add a valid  *
* App ID inside the AndroidManifest. Google Ad Manager publishers should     *
* follow instructions here: https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/quick-start#update_your_androidmanifestxml                           *
******************************************************************************
```

Seguí los pasos y pude correr mi app sin problemas. Gracias